# $L_2((-2,2))$ function that has $L_1((-1,1))$ discrete derivative but not derivative

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to find an example of a function $u\in L_2((-2,2))$ such that $||\delta_h(u)||_{L_1((-1,1))}$ is uniformly bounded in $0<|h|<1/2$ but $u'$ is not in $L_1((-1,1))$. Where $\delta_h(u)(x) = \frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h}$.

My idea is to use a Lipschitz continuous function that is not everywhere differentiable, but all the examples I can come up to have derivatives in $L_1((-1,1))$. If someone told me whether I am in the right track or should look for another kind of functions I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: A function is Lipschitz-continuous if and only if (it is continuous and) its distributional derivative belongs to $L^\infty$. Since $L^\infty(-1,1) \subset L^p(-1,1)$ for all $1 \leqslant p < \infty$, Lipschitz functions cannot be what you look for.

Comment: @DanielFischer great, I did not know that. Thank you very much, I'll start looking another way.

Comment: I would look at Dirac, if $u'$ means the distributional derivative. If it means a pointwise (almost everywhere defined) classical derivative, it's going to be more difficult.